# After log in with Facebook in middle of application how we can get friends list from Facebook using Android?

Tags: android

In my application first I login with Facebook. In the middle off the application I have tried this example `FriendPickerSample` but I did't get the friends list:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.karme/com.karme.newswire.Buddies}:
com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot use SessionLoginBehavior
SSO_WITH_FALLBACK when com.facebook.LoginActivity is not declared as
an activity in AndroidManifest.xml
```

If I place the below code in manifest. It's not logging in to Facebook:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/applicationId" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `com.facebook.LoginActivity` activity to AndroidManifest.xml.

You need to add this to your manifest :

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_facebook_login" >
</activity>
```

Also check that you followed the steps on the "Create a new Android Project with Facebook Login" section , specially those regarding adding the *app_id* string to res/values/strings.xml, the INTERNET permission, the com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId Meta Data, and finally the mentioned LoginActivity.